# Concave lens path of ray

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

What will be the path of ray passing through the first focal length of a biconcave thin lens kept in air?

I know that a ray passing through focus or appearing to pass through focus of a thin lens becomes parallel to the principal axis. But in this case I cannot see how? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ray passing from the focus, after the lens overlaps with the one that starts from the tip of the virtual image, see the image. (Basically that ray is not a "special" one).

[image]

Comment: But shouldn't a ray passing through the focus be parallel to the principal axis of the lens?

Comment: on a positive lens only.

Comment: try [this software](http://jeanmarie.biansan.free.fr/optgeo.html) to play with optics

Comment: @Utkarsh Barsaiyan do you find the answer acceptable? if yes, consider accepting it